# parse json in html from vue js

Tags: jquery, html, vue.js

I am new to Vue js.

I am trying to parse json into the html table with

```
<tr v-for="(item) in products">
   <td>{{item.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

but the table prints empty rows.
and if i try to print

```
<td>{{item}}</td>
```

then each row print single character of the json.

my json :  **"{id: 'mu'}"**

[here is the screenshot of the table that prints single character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbD0F.png)

where I am wrong. Please, a little guidance would help.

```
var app4 = new Vue({
el: '#Itemlist',
data: {
    products: []
},

mounted: function (){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax ({
        url: "getAll",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            self.products = "{id: 'mu'}";
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
}

})
```

Comment: the products variable needs to be an array, so [{id: 'mu'}]

Comment: @ChrisDixon I tried this too, but now 2 more empty rows are added.

Comment: You're setting products to a string, rather than an array... I'll add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app4 = new Vue({
el: '#Itemlist',
data: {
    products: []
},

mounted: function (){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax ({
        url: "getAll",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            // this is your issue
            //self.products = "{id: 'mu'}";

            self.products.push({id: 'mu'});
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
}

})
```

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.